# Magento enterprise showing wrong result to show dynamic data in product listing page for FPC cache

Tags: php, magento, caching, magento-fpc

Magento showing wrong result for dynamic data in product listing page due to FPC. If I disable full page cache its showing perfect. I am facing problem to show the wishlist icon in product listing page.

Please suggest how I can fix that issue, I have tried to fix that issue using magento hole-punching , but unfortunately its not worked.

Same issue I am facing in product details page as well for wishlist icon. If user click on 'add to wish list' button after refreshing that page its again showing the same button instead of 'added to wishlist' due to page cache.

Answer (score -1):

For these dynamic blocks you need to create a small block and then call data from there. the module consist of

- etc/cache.xml
- model class that extend Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract
- block class that extend Mage_Core_Block_Template defining cache_lifetime,cache_tags and cache_key in constructor.

thank you